# Cannot convert string to IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#

I need to convert `string` to `IEnumerable<string>` by every newline character.

I just want the same functionality as `File.ReadLines` **without loading any file, rather taking it from a previously loaded string**.

Comment: `"someString".Split('\n')`?

Comment: it solved the issue @canton7

Comment: @canton7 Actually `.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.None)` would be a better choice.

Comment: @juharr Actually, it depends on the requirements. Who's to say their string has line endings which match `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: If you want *identical* behaviour to `File.ReadLines` (i.e., it auto-determines the line endings), use `var reader = new StringReader("someString")`, then call `reader.ReadLine()` until it returns `null`.

Comment: @canton7 Yeah, actually to get the same as `File.ReadLine` it has to split on `\n` or `\r` or the combination of `\r\n`

Comment: Yes, which is what `StringReader` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) can split your string and give you `string[]`

Usage

```cs
string someString = ...;
string[] lines = someString.Split('\n');
IEnumerable<string> linesAsEnumerable = lines;

DoSomethingWithLines(linesAsEnumerable);
```

Comment: Or even better `IEnumerable<string> lines = someString.Split(Environment.NewLine);`.

Comment: @Alejandro It has to be `Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.None)` because `Environment.NewLine` is a `string` and there is no override of `Split` that just takes a single `string` argument.

Comment: @Alejandro, yes, but I've created `string[]` variable to show actual return type. `IEnumerable<string>` slower to process than raw array

Comment: @Alejandro The question specifically specified the newline character, not the OS's new line character sequence.  Given that they're not reading a file, there's no reason to assume the OS's new line string is what that string uses.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it according to the newline character:

```cs
String[] lines = fileContenets.Split('\n');
```